# Video swapping scrolling effect on HTML JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replicate this video scrolling swap effect.
https://malinowskiego.com/en.

I'm not a web developer so coding is not my thing, so I am using chat gpt to help and achieve that effect, but I seem to gfet on a loop of errors, from not swapping vidoes to just ignoring other videos.

I hope you can help me, because what I have right now is, a video bg that changes on section, but I am missing that in btween transition video

This is the code that I am using so far.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Color Transition Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="aptbg.css">
</head>
<body>

<section class="video-wrapper" id="section-1">
  <div class="video-container">
    <video id="videoBg" class="video-bg" autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="hero_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="color-section red-section" id="section-2">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</section>

<section class="color-section blue-section" id="section-3">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
</section>

<section class="color-section green-section" id="section-4">
  <h1>Section 4</h1>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="swapvideos.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

.color-section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.red-section {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.blue-section {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
}

/* Add these styles for the green section */
.green-section {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.green-section h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* Ensure scrollbar is visible */
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .color-section {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const videoElement = document.getElementById('videoBg');
  const videoSources = ['hero_1.mp4', 'hero_2.mp4', 'hero_3.mp4', 'hero_4.mp4'];
  const videoDurations = [4000, 1000, 4000, 1000]; // in milliseconds
  let currentVideoIndex = 0;

  function changeVideoSource(index) {
    videoElement.src = videoSources[index];
    videoElement.load();
    videoElement.play();
  }

  function handleSectionChange(entries) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        const sectionId = entry.target.id;
        handleVideoChange(sectionId);
      }
    });
  }

  function handleVideoChange(sectionId) {
    switch (sectionId) {
      case 'section-2':
        // Swap from hero_3 to hero_1 (when going back from section-3 to section-2)
        if (currentVideoIndex === 2) {
          changeVideoSource(0);
          currentVideoIndex = 0;
        }
        break;
      case 'section-3':
        // Swap from hero_1 to hero_3
        if (currentVideoIndex === 0) {
          changeVideoSource(2);
          currentVideoIndex = 2;
        }
        // Swap from hero_2 to hero_3
        else if (currentVideoIndex === 1) {
          changeVideoSource(2);
          currentVideoIndex = 2;
        }
        break;
      // Exclude Section 4
    }
  }

  const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.5,
  };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleSectionChange, options);

  // Observe the target sections
  observer.observe(document.getElementById('section-2'));
  observer.observe(document.getElementById('section-3'));

  // Play the initial video (hero_1)
  changeVideoSource(0);
});
```